# K-means and EM algorithms

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means, image-segmentation

How can I implement the k-means & EM algorithms without calling the openCV functions to do the image segmentation?

I begin with this code :

```
#include opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp
#include iostream

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("testImage.png", 0);
    Mat label_img;
    label_img.create(img.cols, img.rows, CV_8UC1);
}
```

How can I continue ?

Comment: Good start, keep going...

Comment: Thanks but how can I implement the k-means & EM algorithms with out calling the openCV functions to do the image segmentation?

Comment: By coding the next step. Give it a shot, and if you have trouble with it, come back and see us.

Comment: ok how can I start coding with out implementation !! .. I should first know how can I implement it

Answer (score 0):

K-means work very simply by iterating two steps till convergence, the E-step and the M-step.

#### Initialization:

Assign each pixel, at random, to one of `k` clusters. That is, for each entry in your `label_img` choose a number `[0..k-1]` at random.

#### Expectation (E-step)

given an assignment of pixels to clusters (`label_img`), you can compute the center of each cluster (simply the mean of pixel values assigned to that cluster).
At the end of this stage you'll have `k` vectors pointing at the centers of your `k` clusters.

#### Maximization (M-step)

Once you have `k` clusters, you compute the distance of each pixel to the `k` centers and assign it (by changing the respective entry in `label_img`) to the center closest to the pixel.
At the end of this stage you'll have a new assignment of each pixel to clusters (new values of `label_img`)

You need to repeat these two steps until `label_img` does not change anymore or if you exceed a pre-defined number of iterations.

Comment: Hi @Shai ,  thanks for help .. please see what is the missing in my code                         I've added the code on the answer section

Comment: @faho0odywbas First, please do not post code as answer, edit your question to reflect your progress. Second, k-means is an example of EM algorithm. Third, try and implement a function for each step: init, e-step and m-step

Comment: Hi Mr. @Shai , I'm sorry, I don't know how can I add the code as comment, because when I add it here, it doesn't looks clear...  Now you mean make the k mean as an initial step ? ,, and if so , how can I do that ?

Comment: @faho0odywbas I did not mean as a comment. Just edit the question itself to reflect your progress.

Answer (score 0):

```
include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void kmeans(const Mat frame, Mat label) {
}

void em(const Mat frame, const Mat label, Mat new_label) {
}

void main()
{
Mat frame;
Mat label_img;
Mat em_label;

frame = imread("testImage.png", 0);

kmeans(frame, label_img);

em(frame, label_img, em_label);
label_img.create(frame.cols, frame.rows, CV_8UC1);

label_img.ptr<float>(25)[30] = 0;
label_img.ptr<float>(25)[31] = 255;

}
```